# Integrating $\int y z e^{zx}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

In the first step of this equation, why does $z$ disappear? I don't understand why we had to get that $dx = (1/z)\,du$

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Pictures of mathematical formulas and other text are [discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). Please typeset your image using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why $z$ disappears is because it gets cancelled out with the $z$ that was already in the integrand. More specifically, we have

$$\int yze^{zx}\,dx=\int(yze^{u})\times \frac{1}{z} \, du = \int ye^u \, du= y\int e^u \, du$$

where the substitution $u=zx$ was used (as in your screenshot) with  a differential ellement $dx=\frac{1}{z} \, du$. Note that we need to change the value with which we integrate with respect to when we do substitutions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's simpler if you write it like this: $$ \int y e^{zx} \big( z\,dx\big) = \int y e^u\,du. $$

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that $y$ and $z$ are constant. So
$$\int y z e^{zx} \, dx = y z \int e^{zx} \,dx $$
and then we invert
$${d\over dx}e^{zx}=z e^{zx}$$
to get
$$\int e^{zx}\,dx = {1\over z}e^{zx}+C.$$
Changing variables is unnecessary here, although it may serve as a simple demonstration of the change of variables method for an integral which can be performed without it.